# How Can I know from code if the MCR Matlab is installed or not?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I would like to know if the MCR Matlab is installed on the pc from Matlab code. How can I do? Is there a way to know this?
Can I find a specified key in Windows registries?

Thank anyone can help me...

Comment: Why do you want to know this? What's the bigger problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check outside matlab or your deployed m-code if MCR is available, search for a `mclmcrrt*.dll` in the list of registered DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

To know if a toolbox is installed, use [`ver`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/ver.html) with the toolbox folder name as input argument. For example:

```
name = 'images'; %// name of toolbox folder
s = ver(name);
```

This gives you a structure `s`:

```
s = 
       Name: 'Image Processing Toolbox'
    Version: '7.1'
    Release: '(R2010b)'
       Date: '03-Aug-2010'
```

If `s` is non-empty (`~isempty(s)`), the toolbox is installed.

Now you only have to find out the name of the MCR folder (maybe `'MCR'` or `'compiler'`?). You can find it out from a Matlab installation that includes the MCR.